# How Can You Define a Custom Path to Nmap Resources?

Tags: nmap

I am working on creating an application that utilizes Nmap, and my goal is to allow the user to run the application without any dependencies.  The issue I've run into is that the Nmap command fails to detect the OS or vendor of any host once I uninstall Nmap from my development machine.  How can I bundle the resources Nmap requires and specify their location to Nmap? Ideally, I would like to execute a command from the Terminal with information on the location of these resources.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on Security.SE. This question being very specific to Nmap, it may be more suited on [NMap project mailing list](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/).

Comment: Thank you! I have since found an answer to this question, but in the future I will use the Nmap mailing list.

Comment: Be aware that [Nmap's license](https://nmap.org/book/man-legal.html) has very strict requirements for software that bundles it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure if I plan to distribute the application, but I'll certainly review the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since found the answer to this question.  In any Nmap command, you can add the `--datadir` argument in order to supply a custom location for the Nmap data.  You can find the required files here: https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/

ex: `nmap --datadir ~/nmapdatafolder localhost`

https://nmap.org/book/data-files-replacing-data-files.html